# const parameter and const method in c++

Tags: c++, constants

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    const int GetValue()
    {   
        return 2;
     }
}
```

and I am passing it to a function like this:

```
void Test(const MyClass &myClass)
{
   int x=myClass.GetValue();
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
The object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with member function Object type is const MyClass
```

I know that if I define function like this:

```
void Test( MyClass &myClass)
```

But I want to know why adding const should generate such error?

Answer (score 8):

You need to make the member function `const`, not the return type:

```
int GetValue() const;
```

This makes it possible to call this member on a `const` instance (or via a `const` reference or pointer).

Note: as you are returning by value, the constness of the thing you return is decoupled from the constness of the object returning it. In fact, it is very unlikely that you want the return type to be `const`.

Answer (score 1):

You set the int to const, try making the method const like so:

```
const int GetValue() const
{   
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to return a `const` value (although it doesn't really matter for a simple type like `int`).

Comment: @Jepessen: Because it inhibits move semantics: a `const` return value can't be moved from, so `x = const_thing()` would require a copy. Not a problem for `int`, but could cause performance issues if you return a large data structure.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems, a visibility problem (your `const int GetValue()` function is not visible since private) and the fact that you're calling a non-const function (which can perform modifications to the object which has it as a member function)

```
const int GetValue()
```

from a constant reference to the class

```
const MyClass &myClass
```

you are basically asking for "*This object shall not be modified, anyway let me call a function which does not guarantee this*".

You're not being coherent.

Comment: No, using a const value to initialise a non-const copy isn't the problem - that's a perfectly reasonable thing to do. The problem is calling a non-const member function on a const object.